# Windows calculator app crashes with WerFault inconsistently when launched from a Service using CreateProcessAsUserW()

Tags: windows, go, winapi, dll

The Windows Service is written in Go, and attempts to create a calculator process in user context using `CreateProcessAsUserW()`.

The code for it is inspired from this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/LiamHaworth/1ac37f7fb6018293fc43f86993db24fc#file-native-go

Most of the time, the calculator app launches in the active user; however, sometimes the app launch fails, but `CreateProcessAsUserW()` doesn't return any error.

Inspection with Procmon reveals that, while launching the calculator app, the app crashes and resorts to collecting WerFault dumps. Unfortunately, I don't see the detailed dumps in the event-logs.

**WerFault crash observed in ProcMon**

[image]

**Detailed Stack trace of 3 similiar calculator app launches using `CreateProcessAsUserW` - First two succeeded and third one in box failed**

[image]

This error is quiet random in nature, which doesn't make the app be reliable. I am quite clueless on what/how to debug from here, and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: [Compile](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator) it yourself and test with that.

Comment: I have a custom compiled app in place of calculator, but irrespective of the app , the crash is observed. I don't see the app being launched successfully.

Comment: for what user token is duplicated ? this not need. for research crash - need debug child process

Comment: User token is duplicated and impersonated ; the app launch works but fails randomly. Can you please brief on how i can debug child process

Comment: i simply hint - not not need duplicate token returned by WTSQueryUserToken. in case usual debugger dont know

Comment: *"This error is quiet random in nature"* - If you want predictable results, don't use a language that's non-deterministic by design. C is OK in this department, so is Rust, or C++ (when/if [Carbon](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang) or [Cppfront](https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront) arrive). Or [Zig](https://ziglang.org/).

Comment: @go_der Start the process using the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag.  Once the process has been launched, you can attach a debugger to the process, then resume the process, and then debug the crash as needed.

Comment: @remyLebeau can you provide few hints on what i can look to debug .procmon does provide information related to app name , cmd args etc that are passed from createProcessAsUserW () .

Comment: @go_der you said you have a custom app you can launch instead of calc and get the same crash.  So debug that app the same way you would debug any custom project.

Comment: Given that the error is similar while launching other apps as well ( calculator) , do you think the error could be with the custom app?

Comment: @go_der Write the simplest possible C# program and if that crashes too you should edit your question and add the code. If it doesn't, add parts from the calculator app to your C# app until the crash occurs. At the same time, remove parts from the calculator app until the crash no longer occurs. Eventually, a single change will cause the app to crash. Ideally you would start with adding/removing large chunks of code to speed up the process. This is known as delta debugging and is (in theory) guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to have occured because of wrong compilation environments where a binary created with x64 was run on  arm64.Thanks all for your inputs